Flutter versione 3.22.3 give me An error was encountered processing the command
[Insert the complete error message here]
Does anyone know how I can resolve this? Thanks in advance for your help!
Lost connection to device.
Error: Unable to terminate viewsoftware.quote on 5582FF0C-0E92-4BA5-BF8B-6808F365111A:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 3:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
Simulator device failed to terminate viewsoftware.quote.
found nothing to terminate
Underlying error (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
    The request to terminate "viewsoftware.quote" failed. found nothing to terminate
    found nothing to terminate
  Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl terminate 5582FF0C-0E92-4BA5-BF8B-6808F365111A viewsoftware.quote
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.

